# Nativescript error only on google play store

Tags: android, google-maps, nativescript

I deploy with success an application to google play in alpha stage.

I'm using the nativescript command `tns build android --release`

The application installed through app store rises the exception:

> Calling js method onMapReady failed TypeError:
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener is not a
>   constructor File:
>   "xxx/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-view.js,
>   line: 208, column: 46

But using `tns run android` with the application on USB works.
Also uploading the application through usb with `adb install my-release.apk` also works.

What could be different in app store apk?

I create a bug in https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/issues/115

Comment: On what API Level and device did this occur? I think you can see that in the crash reports for your alpha release

Comment: Android 6.0. But is the same device I use to upload the exactly same apk from usb.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, android sdk tools need to be upgrade to 25.2.4 and android sdk platform tools to 25.0.3

I was previous using the tools installed in nativescript tutorial.

After the upgrade using android sdk manager, make a new build.